# Combine two database

Tags: r, sas

I have a lot data.

First, database:

```
 Age    A16     A17     A18.5   A23     A25     A27     A30     A35
 2      13.6    14.29   15.24   17.54   18.36   19.07   19.99   21.2
 2.08   13.58   14.26   15.2    17.49   18.31   19.03   19.95   21.16
 2.17   13.55   14.23   15.16   17.45   18.26   18.98   19.9    21.11
...

 3      13.3    13.94   14.83   17.05   17.85   18.57   19.5    20.75
 3.08   13.27   13.91   14.8    17.01   17.82   18.54   19.47   20.72
 3.17   13.25   13.89   14.77   16.98   17.79   18.5    19.44   20.7
 3.25   13.23   13.86   14.74   16.95   17.75   18.47   19.41   20.67
 3.33   13.21   13.84   14.71   16.91   17.72   18.44   19.38   20.65
 3.42   13.19   13.81   14.68   16.88   17.69   18.41   19.36   20.63
 3.5    13.16   13.79   14.66   16.85   17.66   18.38   19.33   20.61
 3.58   13.14   13.76   14.63   16.83   17.63   18.36   19.31   20.6
 3.67   13.12   13.74   14.61   16.8    17.61   18.33   19.29   20.59

 etc...
```

each age gap 0.08

/*****************************************************************************/

Second, database:

```
ID       ID_age            count
A1       3.5783709788      19.193840254
A2       3.3675564682      14.517063788
A3       2.12183436        14.951514375
.....
```

/******************************************************************************/

IF I Want then new data look like

```
ID       ID_age            count            group
A1       3.5783709788      19.193840254     M3
A2       3.3675564682      14.517063788     M1
A3       2.12183436        14.951514375     M1
```

/************************************************************/

So I divided into four group in each age

> sas code

```
if 3<=age<3.08    and  0<count<14.83 then group='M1';
if 3<=age<3.08    and  14.83<=count<17.85 then group='M2';
if 3<=age<3.08    and  17.85<=count<19.5 then group='M3';
if 3<=age<3.08    and  19.5<=count  then group='M4';



if 3.08<=age<3.17 and  0<count<14.8 then group='M1';
if 3.08<=age<3.17 and  14.8<=count<17.82 then group='M2';
if 3.08<=age<3.17 and  17.82<=count<19.44 then group='M3';
if 3.08<=age<3.17 and  19.44<=count  then group='M4';
```

but, the first database have a lot.

I have do many time about if code.

have another way to smart working.

Thanks help.

Comment: Please show how you have tried to solve your problem. Post your current code and say what isn't working about it.

Comment: Also, how are the two databases related?

Comment: I use the if-code, recoding the second database. But the first data are too many. And the program is lengthy. The "age" connects two databases. How can I do the fast?

Comment: Try to recreate an example of `df-1` & `df-2`and run with what you coded so far based on all or few conditions. Then show the desired output, rather than asking someone else to do the complete job for you.